# How to solve this formula in R for specific days for the whole year?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm a beginner in R.

I'd like to calculate the load for 3 water quality parameters in R for specific days for the whole year using the following formula:
[image]

Using the previous formula, I'd like to calculate 7 scenarios. Each scenario represent 1 day of the week (Monday of each week, Tuesday of each week....) for the whole year.

[image]
Using 1 year dataset (could be downloaded from  [here](http://www.dropbox.com/s/y3pmkbvdhu28xub/Data1.csv?dl=0)), I have tried to write a code in Rstudio to calculate 7 scenarios for the whole year but it didn't work.

```
> Q=Flow
> C=NH4
> LN=(Q*C)
> LD=C
> LD=Q
> Q=Flow
> C=NH4
> LN=(Q*C)
> LD=Q
> L=(sum(LN[Date=="Saturday"]))/(sum(LD[Date=="Saturday"]))
> L
[1] NaN
```

I'd appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is purely about coding in R. Please review advice in the Help Center on software-related questions.

Comment: @NickCox 
Apologies, I haven't read this section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to actually test it (I mean, under R), but try

```
tapply( 1:length( NH4 ), as.factor( Day ), function( x ) { return( weighted.mean( NH4[ x ], Flow[ x ] ) ) } )
```

Comment: @ Tamas Ference Thanks for your help. I have got the following error
tapply(1:length(NH4), as.factor(Day), function(x) {return(weighted.mean(NH4[x], Flow[x])})
Error: unexpected '}' in "tapply(1:length(NH4), as.factor(Day), function(x) {return(weighted.mean(NH4[x], Flow[x])}"

Comment: @aelwan : Ah, I missed a closing parenthesis. I corrected it.

Comment: @ Tamas 
I can't thank you enough for your great help

Comment: In your code, there is weighted.mean. What if the formula doesn't include flow weighted like this one https://www.dropbox.com/s/chganh8tb7yrls2/3.jpg?dl=0
How can I select specific days in my calculation?

Comment: @aelwan: You can go on with `tapply` in the exact same way for _any_ formula you have. Just replace the `return( )` in `function( x ) { return( ) }` with the formula you need, remembering that `NH4[ x ]` will correspond to the vector of $C$s in your formula and `Flow[ x ]` to $Q$s

Comment: Many thanks for your help. In your formula, you sorted the calculation as a function of the day (fixed sampling). You used the day as facotr. What if I want to do it randomly without considering the same day each week. For example (Monday of the 1st week with Tuesday of the 2nd week with Friday of the 3rd week.....)? Could you please illustrate to me how can I do that?